# Missing values in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

I want to call a URL with jQuery and parse only one value from the HTML I get as response. The problem is that the span-tag, where the value should be, is empty.

```
$.ajax({
          url: url,
          success: function(data) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var responseDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");

            console.log(responseDoc);

            var score = responseDoc.getElementById('score');
            console.log('Score: ' + score.innerHTML);
          }
        });
```

Does anybody know if and how I can get the value?

Comment: Which is the value returned by `data` when function is successful?

Comment: Do you have the url you are trying to access?

Comment: I tried to access the url and it worked fine. And data is an HTML response object.

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery you can simply use it's own method here like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        var myVal = $(data).find('span#mydata').text();
        console.log(myVal);
    }
});
```

If code above is not working, you should check your output if that span tag or whatever you are looking for is inside the response at all.

Comment: Does not work as well. I think it's because the value is calculated with Javascript after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because the value was - as I thought - calculated with javascript. The solution was to load the script from the server and call the function needed to calculate the value.